# Changing response due to the mention after command

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have this command called `p!profile` which sends the user's profile. I want it so that someone executes the command `p!profile @someone` my bot would send the person's profile.
I am not the best coder in the world, sorry. Also, thank you for those who helped me in the past <3

```py
@client.command
async def profile(ctx, mention):
  if ctx.mention == ctx.author:
        #code
  else:
        #code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `mention` as an `arg`, you can use [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member). You can initially define this as `None` in case the person executing your `p!profile` command does not mention anyone.

```py
@client.command()
async def profile(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if user == None or user == ctx.author:
        user = ctx.author # converts user to ctx.author if user is None or the person mentioned themselves
    else:
        # other code here
```

I have made a command like this before, here is the above working.
[image: Not mentioning someone and it gives you ctx.author]
[image: Mentioning someone and it gives you user]